# nokia error code 217 - jar manifest end of line

Tags: java, java-me, nokia, midp, j2mepolish

I have developed a J2ME application with J2ME Polish. Nokia now validate contents that will be submitted to the store, the challenge is that during validation of my JAR and JAD files, I get  `Error 217 - The JAR manifest does not end with a new line`

I checked my JAR manifest and finds out that it is ending with a new line. Is anyone having any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: remove the new line and try it.

Comment: I tried editing the jar manifest with netbeans editor but it is readonly

Comment: have you open it with notepad ?

Comment: except i uncompress the jar file itself, that way i was able to edit the manifest file, but i don't know how to copy back the update to the jar file

Comment: Use the jar command line with -u switch to update. See http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/jar/basics/update.html

Comment: Other things to check: what sort of newline are they expecting? Depending on the character encoding of your OS a different form of newline may be used.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i used the jar tool to extract and make the changes(removing the new line as suggested by Lucifer) and updated. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check that there are no invisible characters like whitespace or tab at the last line of the manifest.

If manifest has a newline indeed, error message apparently means a bug in this Nokia device.

Still, it is possible that your manifest has something wrong and that Nokia only used incorrect message to indicate some other problem in it. Getting messages like this, make sure that your manifest conforms to respective sections of JAR file Specification ([available online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html)), particularly:

- [Manifest Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Manifest%20Specification)
- [Notes on Manifest and Signature Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Notes%20on%20Manifest%20and%20Signature%20Files)

First I'd check is that manifest lines do not exceed *"72 bytes (not characters), in its UTF8-encoded form"*.

Another thing worth trying is to experiment with various styles of line endings of those specified: `CR LF | LF | CR`. In your IDE / build there could be a setting to manage that, look for something called like "DOS / Unix / Mac line breaks". Specification states that all these are OK, but you better account for a chance of bug in the device not being able to recognize particular style line breaks.

Also consider checking / asking at Nokia forums for this might be a known issue with particular device.

Comment: Thanks guys, finally got the error off, i used the jar command suggested by Dan Gravell to extract the manifest from the jar file, edit and update.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this, i used the jar tool provided by the java sdk to extract the midlet from the jar file like this:

```
jar xf myjarfile.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

then edited the file in a text editor and updated the manifest in the jar file

```
jar umf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF myjarfile.jar
```

Thanks for suggestions guys.

Answer (score 0):

optionally you can open your jar file using winrar software then you can access the manifest from the META - INI file.from this you can edit it using the text editor after which you can save CAUTION:after saving note that the size is going to change so make sure you check the size of the jar after you have edited , by right clicking then view properties.check the size then change it accordingly to jad file by opening your jad file in a text editor

thats it:-0